# ParametricPlot shows nothing when changing a parameter?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, parametric-functions

I need to plot the inverse function with `ParametricPlot`
$$x=-c_2+\int_1^y\frac{dt}{\sqrt{c_1t-f(t)/2-50t\ln[tf(t)]}}, \quad (1)$$

where the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$ determined by function $f(t)=\frac{1}{0.1+t}$ and parameter $m$. I used the following code. Strangely, I found that when I decreased $m$ less than $1$, `ParametricPlot` showed noting, while it works well when $m\ge1$.

However, I do need the plot with $m<1$. I think the problem could be related to the integration limit. How do I fix it? Please give me some suggestion. Thank you very much.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[t_] := 1/(0.1 + t);
m = 1;
(*m=2;*)
(*m=1/2;*)
c1 = f[m]/(2*m) + 50*Log[m*f[m]];
F[t_] := 1/Sqrt[c1*t - f[t]/2 - 50*t*Log[t*f[t]]];
c2 = Re[NIntegrate[F[t], {t, 1, m}]] // Quiet;
plot = ParametricPlot[{-c2 + NIntegrate[F[t], {t, 1, y}, MaxRecursion -> 6, 
PrecisionGoal -> 12], y}, {y, 0, m},
PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> 10, 
MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, 
MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red],
Frame -> True, Axes -> False] // Quiet
```

The output with $m\ge1$ looks like

[image]

**Update**: I also observed the radicand `radicand[t_] = c1*t - f[t]/2 - 50*t*Log[t*f[t]]`,

```
Plot[radicand[t], {t, 0, m}]
```

[image]

As we can see, there are an interval, on which the radicand less than zero. I think it has something to do with the problem. However, I could I exclude these negative values of the radicand?

Comment: In c2 try {t,0,m }

Comment: Hi @OkkesDulgerci just try it, still noting for $m<1$, I am wondering what is your point?

Comment: Real part of integral is zero  if upper bound is less than or equal to lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

This works. I don't know this is what you want.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[t_] := 1/(0.1 + t);
m = 0.4;
c1 = f[m]/(2*m) + 50*Log[m*f[m]]
F[t_] := 1/Sqrt[c1*t - f[t]/2 - 50*t*Log[t*f[t]]]
c2 = NIntegrate[F[t], {t, 0.1, m}]
plot = ParametricPlot[{-c2 + 
 NIntegrate[F[t], {t, 0.1, y}, MaxRecursion -> 6, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 12], y}, {y, 0, m}, PlotPoints -> 20,    MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> 10,    MeshFunctions -> {#1 &},    MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red], Frame -> True,    Axes -> False] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: thanks@Okkes Dulgerci, it looks very like what I am looking for. But, it again doesn't work if reducing $m$ a little, say, to $0.39$. However, I found that if increasing the lower limit of `NIntegrate`, say, to $0.2$, the above code works all the way down to $0.2$ but not further. Could you suggest some recipe for tuning the lower limit of integration and why it works if one increase it? Thanks again!

Comment: I noticed that you have removed `Re` in evaluating $c_2$. Could you please add some comments?